# Unhandled exception not stopping execution

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, unhandled-exception

I have the following code in my application, which is handling the `Load` event in  `System.Windows.Forms.Form`:

```
Private Sub frmBillingPoller_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Throw New Exception("I should be unhandled")

End Sub
```

When I place a breakpoint on the method signature I can see there are no `Try...Catch` statements anywhere in the call stack.  As far as I know VB.NET doesn't have any attributes or settings that ignore unhandled exceptions (although it wouldn't suprise me).

So why in this particular case does the exception not halt execution?

Comment: x64 system? Search for Form_Load on x64 system swallows exceptions

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for that, I take it there hasn't been any developments in fixes for this?

Comment: No I am not aware of any changes so far. It seems very difficult that anything could change here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you to read this article that explains what happens when you have an exception on the form_load event on a x64 bit OS and your app is compiled for AnyCPU (Meaning that your code executes as 64bit code)

[Visual Studio debugger fails to catch unhandled exception for a Windows Form or WPF Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx)

In my very simple terms. On the scenario above the OS64 catches the exception and the debugger is not informed of this. So you don't see any exception, but the form_load event stops to run.
If you write some other code after the exception, also if it is inside a try/catch block, you will see that the catch block code is not executed. The control returns to the line where you have showed the form.

Comment: Was there a change in AnyCPU behavior in Visual Studio? If I compile with AnyCPU on my x64 bit OS, then program runs in x86 mode. only runs in x64 if I explicitly compile in x64 only. Using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I am not aware of any changes about this on VS2012. Waiting to be enlightened

Comment: Having read that article, does this mean that *anything* called within Main() will have it's exceptions swallowed by the OS?

Comment: As explained in the article, you just need to check that "thrown", and it would be fired as expected. I tested it with an exception in a button, this was fired, so seems to be a bit different with Form_Load

Comment: The article explains that this behavior (exception missed by user code) happens when there is an exception while the code is running in a kernel context. In Form_Load this happens, elsewhere I don't know. When the exception fires, the debugger try to search an exception handler walking back the call stack till the Main method but, as explained, the x64 OS doesn't allow this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your project definition to compile AnyCPU or explicit compile as x86

If you need to build in x64, then one way is to use the menu  Debug -> Exceltions and check all 'Thrown' checkboxes. This makes the program halt on all exceptions, even if they are handled in Try..Catch blocks.